# C++ syntax, array and lambda function ambiguity

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, parameters, lambda

My question is purely syntactical. In C++ we can declare unnamed function parameters. Let's take

`void f( int () )`

It is valid. Just like these ones:

`void f( int f2() )`

`void f( int (f2()) )`first parentheses are just for grouping, albeit with no effect

`void f( int (()) )`first parentheses are just for grouping, albeit with no effect

Now, let's consider

`void f( int [] )`

It is valid. Just like these ones:

`void f( int a[] )`

`void f( int (a[]) )`first parentheses are just for grouping, albeit with no effect

However, this one

`void f( int ([]) )`

is illegal in visual studio. It interprets it as functional cast to lambda. I want to know, whether compiler should support this syntactic construction or it potentially can spawn syntactic ambiguity with lambda or something else. It should be smart enough to see that it is function declaration and not a function call that accepts lambda.

Comment: `void f( int ([]) ) ` works with clang and gcc. Looks like MSVC bug.